# WooCommerce: order details page: insert values from new custom column 'quantity_ordered' in table 'wc_order_product_lookup'

Tags: mysql, woocommerce, orders, product-quantity, customcolumn

#### 1. The problem:

I want to sell perishable items which are weighed (and thus never exactly match in weight what the customer actually ordered) and sometimes if a specific product is no more available, a similar product will be shipped.
e.g.:

```
ordered: 1.000 kg apple (variety A)  
shipped: 0.975 kg apple (variety B)
```

I want the customers to be able to see this in their invoice:

```
Product           | kg ordered | kg shipped  
__________________|____________|___________
apple (variety A) | 1.000 kg   | 0.000 kg
apple (variety B) | 0.000 kg   | 0.975 kg
```

- This means WooCommerce should be "convinced" to handle quantities in both Qty columns/variables (old and custom one) as `float` instead of `integer`.
- Therefore I also need WooCommerce to stop deleting products  with zero quantity (`product_qty`)(when updating an order in the backoffice).

Partial temporary solution:

```
\woocommerce\includes\admin\wc-admin-functions.php
```

Line284:

```
$item->delete();
// $item->delete();
```

- I also want the **new custom column** `product_quantity_ordered` in the table `{prefix}wc_order_product_lookup` (which I created already)(if not 'good practice' - where&how should I add this column?) to get the values from column `product_qty` (in the same table `{prefix}wc_order_product_lookup`) the moment the customer makes his order.

Partial temporary solution:
a SQL query in **phpMyAdmin**:
`UPDATE L16_wc_order_product_lookup SET product_qty_ordered = product_qty WHERE date_created BETWEEN '2020-06-24' AND '2020/07/14';`

- A plus would be to display both quantity columns next to each other (first quantity ordered, then quantity shipped) in both **admin edit order page** and in the **invoice**.

#### 2. What I’ve tried:

1. I added the **new custom column** `product_quantity_ordered` in the table `{prefix}wc_order_product_lookup` (again, if this is not "best practice"... where should I add this new column?)
   see image:
   [image: phpMyAdmin - product_qty_ordered]
2. I used the code snippet from [Show product meta in order items table in Order Details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25644420/show-product-meta-in-order-items-table-in-order-details/25645735#25645735) (which displays the new column column and populates it with values from `product_qty`). However, as soon as I edit the product quantity in the edit order page - of course - WooCommerce updates both quantity columns.
   see image:
   [image]

#### 3. My code:

Only this snippet (from [Show product meta in order items table in Order Details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25644420/show-product-meta-in-order-items-table-in-order-details/25645735#25645735) ) for the time being:

```
add_action('woocommerce_admin_order_item_headers', 'my_woocommerce_admin_order_item_headers');
function my_woocommerce_admin_order_item_headers() {
    // set the column name
    $column_name = 'Qty ordered';
    echo '<th>' . $column_name . '</th>';
}
add_action('woocommerce_admin_order_item_values', 'my_woocommerce_admin_order_item_values', 10, 3);
function my_woocommerce_admin_order_item_values($_product, $item, $item_id = null) {
    $value = $item->get_quantity( 'edit' ); // this line of code stems from Line28 of \woocommerce\packages\woocommerce-admin\src\Overrides\OrderTraits.php 
echo '<td>' . $value . '</td>';
}
```

Comment: I just found a way to prevent WooCommerce from deleting **zero quantity order items**: \woocommerce\includes\admin\wc-admin-functions.php
Line284: <code>$item->delete(); → replace with: // $item->delete();</code>

Comment: I just figured out the correct syntax for the SQL query: UPDATE `L16_wc_order_product_lookup` SET `product_qty_ordered` = `product_qty` WHERE `date_created` BETWEEN '2020-06-24' AND '2020/07/14';